# How to hide a custom navigation bar with animation in Modal view controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, modalviewcontroller, uitoolbar

I made a view controller with collection view and presented it modally. And I also added custom navigation bar and toolbar without navigation controller because I want to present the view controller modally as I said.

So I can't have `navigationController` property on the view controller and can't use `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)` that I exactly wanted.

I temporarily set `isHidden` of each bar to `false` & `true` whenever tapping a screen. But I heard I shouldn't use `isHidden` property directly, and I still want to do that with animation.

Any solution? Did I miss something?

Do I just use `UIView.animate` method?

[Main.storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UdaAp.png)

Comment: I'm not entirely clear about the issue. If I understand it, this VC is being presented modally - as in you are coding `present`? If so, then where is the navigation bar? If in the presented VC - not the present one - why not create *two* VCs? One for the *base* view controller - no navigation - and one *subclassed* that has a navigation bar? I'm assuming you have a need for both - and present as needed. (And please, if I'm the one missing something, let me know what.)

Comment: @dfd Thanks for reply. I attached a screenshot. I used segue to present target VC modally, not using `present`and added 2 bars on target VC like in the screenshot. On this situation, `navigationController` property in target VC is `nil`, so I can't use `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)`. If you need more info, feel free to ask. Thanks.

Comment: It does sound like I can't help. But to be clear, your storyboard image looks like it goes from a VC titled "local" to the second VC? How is this segue triggered?

Comment: @dfd I just used segue from local VC to target VC with "Present Modally", and implemented `prepare()` method in local VC. Still you can't help me with this issue?

Comment: Now I'm **really** confused. A few hours ago I posted a comment to this question and **a second** one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65268350/how-to-determine-whether-current-view-controller-is-active-and-execute-code-if?noredirect=1#comment115389653_65268350. They are way too similar... presenting something via a storyboard modally. I also double-checked and thought **you** were @AnthonSanthez asking two similar questions. So - my bad. See my answer there. It involves using notifications. If needed? I guess I can cross post it.

Comment: Sorry, to finish... I posted an answer to that other question, not a comment. And I swear, at the time (after checking) I thought you posted the same question twice, with some variation.

Comment: @dfd Thanks for a link. But I guess this issue is not relevant to the link. I just simply want to know if I can hide toolbar and navigation bar with animation not using Navigation controller object and `setNavigationBarHidden(_:animated:)`.