# How to determine whether current view controller is active, and execute code if active

Tags: swift, viewcontroller

In my app, there is a ViewController.swift file and a popupViewController.swift file. Inside the app, when I open the popupViewController with storyboard segue as presentModally and then come back from popupViewController to ViewController with the code `dismiss()`, the methods `viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, ViewWillLayoutSubviews` etc. nothing works, they execute just once and don't repeat when I go and return back. So, I want to execute the code every time when viewController.swift is active. I couldn't find a useful info in stackoverflow about this.

Meanwhile, I don't know much about notification and observers(if certainly needed), therefore, can you tell step by step in detail how to do that in Swift (*not objective-c*)? I mean how to determine if current view controller is active.

Edit: I am navigating from StoryBoard segue, presentModally. There is no Navigation Controller in storyboard.

I tried some codes but nothing happens. The point I came so far is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(appWillEnterForeground), name:UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil) 
}

@objc func appWillEnterForeground() {
        print("asdad") //nothing happens
        if self.viewIfLoaded?.window != nil {
            // viewController is visible
            print("CURRENT VİEW CONTROLLER") //nothing happens
        }
    }
```

Comment: All four of those are called when navigating back and forth between view controllers via a `UINavigationController`. How are you navigating forward and backwards? Can you provide us with some code?

Comment: @gmdev I am navigating from StoryBoard segue, presentModally. Now updated the post adding this line

Comment: I don't use storyboards, but it sounds like the equivalent to one VC doing a `present` of another one. If so, maybe you could make the first VC be a delegate of the modal one, telling it that it is being dismissed.

Comment: @dfd how to do that? Can you explain more detail? There are only 2 view controllers in the app

Comment: @AnthonSanthez have you added print statements to verify that these methods are not called? For example, putting `print("View will appear")` in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: @gmdev I printed. Nothing happens, even using home button and returning back or using dismiss button at popupViewController, nothing happens in viewWillAppear method

Comment: Can you post the relevant code that is responsible for pushing the view controller?

Comment: @gmdev This is the code for returning back to the main ViewController.swift file: 
      IBAction func NotNowButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: @AnthonSanthez sorry, I mean the code responsible for displaying the ViewController in the first place, not navigating backwards

Comment: @gmdev I didnt understand. It is the main screen. When the app starts, main screen is displayed which is ViewController.swift file

Comment: I just commented on your other question. Are these two related? (It seems to be.) I'm not asking to be critical. Rather, I have an additional question - somewhat related to my question on your other question. :-) If all you want to do is (a) show one VC and then (b) present the second VC modally, why *not* do it in code instead of a storyboard? You have more control over things.

Comment: @AnthonSanthez what is the `.modalPresentationStyle ` you are setting when you present the view controller modally?

Comment: @gmdev It is the default presentation style of the storyboard. It appears like a popup from the top. Anyway thank you very much for your helps, I found an escape method this time. I really appreciate your effort to helps, this is a real and the best info-sharing website..

Comment: @AnthonSanthez no problem, I'm glad your issue was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mention in my comments, I don't use storyboards. There may be a way to create an unwind segue - or maybe not - but [here's a link][1] that may help you with a storyboard-only way of fixing your issue. A quick search on "modal" turned up 9 hits, and the second one starts going into details.

I'm thinking the issue is with what modality is. Basically, your first view controller, which properly executed `viewDidAppear`, is *still* visible. So it's effectively not executing `viewDidDisappear` when your second VC is presented.

You might want to change your concept a bit - an application window (think `AppDelegate` and/or `SceneDelegate` become *active*, where a `UIViewController` has a  is *initialized* and *deinitialized*, along with a root `UIView` that is *loaded*, appears* and disappears*. This is important, because what you want to do is send your notification from the modal VC's `viewDidDisappear` override.

First, I find it easiest to put all your notication definitions in an extension:

```
extension Notification.Name {
    static let modalHasDisappeared = Notification.Name("ModalHasDisappeared")
}
```

This helps not only reduce string typos but also is allows Xcode's code completion to kick in.

Next, in your first view controller, ad an observer to this notification:

```
init() {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(modalHasDisappeared), name: .modalHasDisappeared, object: nil)
}
required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(modalHasDisappeared), name: .modalHasDisappeared, object: nil)
}
@objc func modalHasDisappeared() {
    print("modal has disappeared")
}
```

I've added *both* forms of `init` for clarity. Since you are using a storyboard, I'd expect that `init(coder:)` is the one you need.

Finally, just send the notification when the modal has disappeared:

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(animated)
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .modalHasDisappeared, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

This sends no data, just the fact that the modal has disappeared. If you want to send data - say, a string or a table cell value, change the `object` parameter to it:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .modalHasDisappeared, object: myLabel, userInfo: nil)
```

And make the following changes in your first VC:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(modalHasDisappeared(_:)), name: .modalHasDisappeared, object: nil)

@objc func modalHasDisappeared(_ notification:Notification) {
    let label = notification.object as! UILabel!
    print(label.text)
}
```

Last notes:

- To repeat, note that by declaring an extension to `Notification.Name`, I've only have one place where I'm declaring a string.
- There is no code in `AppDelegate` or `SceneDelegate`, nor any references to `UIApplication(). Try to think of the view (and view controller) as appearing/disappearing, not background/foreground.
- While the first view is *visually* in the background, it's still visible. So the trick is to code against the modal view disappearing instead.

Comment: thank you very much for that detailed explanation, it is a good summary of what is going on. I handled the problem using a different escape method, so I will give a try for your answer when I get out of escaping alternatives:) Nevertheless, I am accepting your answer since I appreciate your effort and step-by-step understandable teaching style. This info will help others to understand the underlying logic like me, thanks..